# Can't delete field in sharepoint online pnp

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Title is a default column that comes with a generic list which I want to remove. Any idea how to make this work?

Pnp:

```
 # CREATE NEW LIST
 $22 = New-PnPList `
         -Title 'Honours' `
         -Template GenericList `
         -Url lists/honours


# TODO: REMOVE TITLE
$99 = Remove-PnPField `
        -List 'Honours' `
        -Identity 'Title' `
        -Force
```

Error:

```
Remove-PnPField : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
At line:2 char:7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue and I tried different approaches as well but not able to delete the column.

As a workaround, you can hide the Title column. Below is the script for the same.
it will first make the Title column not required and then hide it.

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://contos.com/sites/Test
$context = Get-PnPContext
$web = $context.web
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Honours")
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($list)
$context.Load($list.Fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$field = $list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
$context.Load($field)
$field.Required = $false
$field.Hidden = $true
$field.Update()

$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: I actually love you!!!! <3